# elementary OS Juno starts with a black screen in virtualbox

Tags: release-juno, virtualbox, macintosh

I've installed elementary OS 5 on Parallels Virtual Machine on a Mac and it starts up but has a black screen with the shutdown and network button wording displayed at top right. I've reset and restarted the virtual machine but same results. It did start up originally but was erratic with this problem which has now become a permanent feature.
Windows 10 and Ubuntu Studio both run OK.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Update:**

OK, so
Dumped the file and reinstalled again. Carried out all the updates on offer from the app center and all looked good and behaved well. Installed Firefox, added it to the dock and finally shut down and restarted.
Oh dear back to the same problem of a black screen and doesn't arrive at the login screen at all! So annoying as it was performing really well and very quick!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider a disk partition of your Mac hd
Open `Disk Utility`and add a new partition (I used 100gb), format your new partition to "windows fat"
Download "balena etcher" for Mac
flash a 5-gb USB stick using "balena etcher" with your **elementary.iso**
Boot your Mac pressing and keeping the alt/opt key after the system chime 
Selecting your stick to boot from
Once your Mac runs Juno from your USB stick, install Juno from there to your partition you created before on your Mac hd

Juno is great. I found many good software which can replace Mac. The minimalism in Juno and it's applications helps us to fully focused on our workflow.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not an option for me although I did consider it. As I've paid for and regularly update 'Parallels Virtual Machine' I really need to have Elementary running under it. When initially setting it up it ran beautifully and looked good but when restarting it the same problem arose. As all other Linux variants and Windows 10 seem to run OK under Parallels there must be something I am missing! Thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: :) OK. I think it isn't Juno to cause problems. Rather grub the boot loader. I don't use parallels so I think the efi partition read isn't started correctly, grub cannot start and everything hangs. I would like to be more helpful but Linux isn't my usual work environment. Try to check out the forums of parallels, and if there's no similar case contact them directly you're a client after all.

Comment: Thanks for that, good point and I'll come back if I can get a decent answer! Not my work environment either but am looking at it for development reasons.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to a prompt by Jarold I looked at Parallels support and the answer was to up the memory for graphics to 512Mb and Virtual memory to 8Gb PLUS importantly disable 3D graphics acceleration.

Works quite well at the moment!